# Can't connect to wifi with recommended Edimax EW7811U

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, wireless, xilinx, redpitaya

I can connect via ethernet, but have been trying to setup wifi using the recommended Edimax EW7811U, as mentioned here: https://redpitaya.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200295492-WIFI-connection

I have a Raspberry Pi sitting right next to it, connected with the same type of adapter, and it works fine.  In fact, the Pi is there because it's acting as a bridge, to share my wifi with the Red Pitaya over ethernet, though I'd really like to get that out of the mix.  At least until I have a good reason for the Pi being involved ;)

I've swapped the adapters, so I know it's something with the configuration on the Red Pitaya.
I think my biggest trouble is that I don't know where to find things in this version of Linux.  Where can I find a system log or a wpa_supplicant log?  The usual suspect, '/var/log only', only contains nginx logs.

I also can't find much information on what flavor of Linux the Red Pitaya runs.  I've seen mention of Xilinx, but haven't learned much more from that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why this is off topic.  It's a question for the Red Pitaya.  Other hardware questions have been asked and answered, but this is a software question anyhow.

Comment: I also struggled. Just follow the quick-start instructions exactly, choosing the "connect wirelessly" option. Note that you must restart the Red Pitaya twice like it says.